# Replacing with keyword with acquire and release semaphore methods

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664720/how-to-create-global-lock-semaphore-with-multiprocessing-pool-in-python) I've found following example (this is modified version) of using semaphores with multiprocessing module:

```
#!/bin/env python

import multiprocessing
from time import sleep
import os

max_allowed_processes_in_critical_section=1
semaphore = multiprocessing.Semaphore(max_allowed_processes_in_critical_section)

def do_job(id):
    # BEGINNING OF CRITICAL SECTION
    with semaphore:
        sleep(1)
        print "#####################"
        print "Inside locked semaphore"
        print "PPID: %s" % os.getppid()
        print "PID:  %s" % os.getpid()

    # END OF CRITICAL SECTION
    print("Finished job")

def main():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(6)
    for job_id in range(6):
        print("Starting job")
        pool.apply_async(do_job, [job_id])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As you can see in this context the semaphore is used with `with` keyword. In general semaphores has two methods `wait()` and `signal()`. In python's `threading` and `multiprocessing` modules those methods are AFAIK equivalent to `acquire()` and `release()`. I've rewritten the code to this one, which uses `acquire()` and `release()` methods:

```
#!/bin/env python

import multiprocessing
from time import sleep
import os

max_allowed_processes_in_critical_section=1
semaphore = multiprocessing.Semaphore(max_allowed_processes_in_critical_section)

def do_job(id):
    # BEGINNING OF CRITICAL SECTION
    semaphore.acquire()
    sleep(1)
    print "#####################"
    print "Inside locked semaphore"
    print "PPID: %s" % os.getppid()
    print "PID:  %s" % os.getpid()
    semaphore.release()

    # END OF CRITICAL SECTION
    print("Finished job")

def main():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(6)
    for job_id in range(6):
        print("Starting job")
        pool.apply_async(do_job, [job_id])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

From my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32318389/with-keyword-works-when-openning-file-but-not-when-calling-a-function) I've understood that when some method is used with `with` keyword then `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` methods of context manager are called on entry (and exit respectively) from the body of the `with` statement. So I assume that `acquire()` is called inside `__enter__()` and `release()` is called inside `__exit__()`.

Questions:

1. Is my assumption about calling `acquire()` from `__enter__()` and
   `release()` from `__exit__()` correct?
2. Can I see somehow what are `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` methods doing in this example? I've also noticed that when I access not defined variables in `with` version I don't get any exception (it must be there some exception handling which simply suppress the errors).

E.G. this one does not throw an exception even if `ppid` and `pid` does not exists

```
print "#####################"
print "Inside locked semaphore"
print "PPID: %s" % ppid
print "PID:  %s" % pid
```

3. Is this approach of using semaphores to ensure exclusivity for one process in critical section correct?
4. As a python beginner I did not catch why `BoundedSemaphore([value])` and `Semaphore([value])` are nested under `class multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager` in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) can you please clarify this?

Comment: What does “see somehow” mean?  See the source, see the documentation, or see evidence at run time?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes.
2. You can see this (if only indirectly) in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement).  `with` blocks *can* suppress exceptions, but one for a semaphore shouldn’t do so.  Perhaps there’s a complication in the context of (or there is (or was in 2015) a bug in) `multiprocessing`.
3. That’s one of the uses of semaphores, yes.
4. The names like `Semaphore` under `SyncManager` are functions to create synchronization objects backed by the manager—they’re named like classes as a hint that, like a class, they are called to manufacture new objects.