# Lock.acquire(False) does?

Tags: python, locking

I have a piece of code

```
    locked = lock.acquire(False)
        if locked:  break
```

according to python doc:
**lock.aquire(False):-
When invoked with the blocking argument set to False, do not block. If a call with blocking set to True would block, return False immediately; otherwise, set the lock to locked and return True.**
I quite understand what they said but can somebody simplify this and please explain me in relation to the above code.

Answer (score 6):

By default, [lock.acquire](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock.acquire) will block execution of the thread until the lock is released by a different thread. If you pass `block=False` to the function (as in your example), the call will not block, and will return immediately. Its return value specifies whether or not your thread has actually acquired the lock.

Comment: kwarg should have been `blocking`, not `block`