# How to properly try/catch timeout errors when acquiring a lock in Python 3.4

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

I'm using `threading.RLock` for a multithreaded application. I'd like to have threads try to acquire a lock, and if unsuccessful, retry some number of times provided the time spent retrying is below some timeout threshold.

Here's what I have

```
>>> import threading
>>> lock = threading.RLock()
>>> def worker():
        with lock.acquire(timeout=5):
            print('acquired')
>>> lock.acquire()
>>> t2 = threading.Thread(target=worker)
>>> t2.start()
```

This seems to work, and I get an exception after five seconds of waiting:

```
>>> Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 920, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 868, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 2, in test
AttributeError: __exit__

KeyboardInterrupt
>>> 
KeyboardInterrupt
```

The `AttributeError` seems strange - shouldn't we see some kind of a timeout error?

My questions here are:

1. Am I doing this correctly in Python 3.4? I've been looking at a [similar question asked on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392640/how-to-implement-a-lock-with-a-timeout-in-python-2-7) that seems targeted to Python 2.7. Moreover, I'm somewhat confused why I'd need to use a condition variable if `lock.acquire` accepts a timeout argument.
2. Is there a better pattern for retrying `lock.acquire` with a timeout/delay in between retries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locks are context managers, but `acquire` doesn't return a context manager. It also doesn't throw an exception if it times out.

`Lock.acquire` and `RLock.acquire` return `True` if they acquire the lock and `False` if they don't. To test whether you acquired the lock, simply check the return value. Don't use `with` or `try`-`except`.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense why I'm getting the attribute error - it's not a context manager - Thanks! I'm wondering if you might be able to also clear up the confusion regarding the linked question. Should I be using a condition variable, here?

Comment: @user138440: You don't need a condition variable. The linked question needs to emulate `timeout` because `Lock.acquire` and `RLock.acquire` don't support `timeout` on Python 2.