# How to write logic for conditions occurring for x amount of time

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I am trying to figure out how to do the following:

If "some logic" occurs for more than 15 seconds:
       "execute some code"

Im not quite sure how to ask python to do this. I am working with stock prices and my index column is dtype='datetime64[ns].

I tried searching other threads for hints on how to do this but i wasn't even quite sure what to search for.

Sorry in advance if its a very elementary question.

Comment: To me, it's a very unclear question.

Answer (score 0):

try takinng the current time and comparing it every tick

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to use threads (multiprocessing) as they would be 2 tasks "some logic" and the "scheduler".

This can be addressed easily with the following logic:

```
import threading
import time

lock = threading.Lock()
cond = threading.Condition(threading.Lock())

def waitLock(timeout):
    with cond:
        current_time = start_time = time.time()
        while current_time < start_time + timeout:
            if lock.acquire(False):
                return True
            else:
                cond.wait(timeout - current_time + start_time)
                current_time = time.time()
    return False
```

Source: [How to implement a Lock with a timeout in Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392640/how-to-implement-a-lock-with-a-timeout-in-python-2-7?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

def check():
    if not some_logic(): return False

    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() - start_time <= 15:
        if not some_logic(): return False

    return True

if check():
    ... # do stuff
```

This runs `some_logic` as many times as possible to ensure that it returns `True` *throughout* the whole 15-second period.

Comment: I think this will work! thank you! If i run into a snag il reply again.

Comment: the issue i seem to be running into is that my program runs through each new line of price data like a loop and therefor makes "start_time" a  different value every time the script progresses down the line of data. How do I make it so that start time remains the same every time the scrpit runs through a new line?

Comment: @Sagittar1us19, set `start_time = time.time()` first and then do the looping? Or use multithreading: one thread does the checking, the other one works with data. This really depends on what your code does.

Comment: The trading environment i am using is named backtrader. When putting in the trading strategy you do it in a method that goes through each row of data one by one. Each time the program goes to a new row, it makes that row into [0]. So the only way that the strategy could know if condition is true, is by going through the loop unfortunately.

Comment: I am going to try to store the time the condition is true into a list and then keep checking if the current time - the [0] value in the list is less than 5 . Then clear the list after I have made use of the start time. Hopefully that will work